# Dual-core performance worse than single core?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, vmware

The following nunit test compares performance between running a single thread versus running 2 threads on a dual core machine. Specifically, this is a VMWare dual core virtual Windows 7 machine running on a quad core Linux SLED host with is a Dell Inspiron 503.

Each thread simply loops and increments 2 counters, addCounter and readCounter.  This test was original testing a Queue implementation which was discovered to perform worse on a multi-core machine. So in narrowing down the problem to the small reproducible code, you have here **no queue** only incrementing variables and to shock and dismay, it's far slower with 2 threads then one.

When running the first test, the Task Manager shows 1 of the cores 100% busy with the other core almost idle.  Here's the test output for the single thread test:

```
readCounter 360687000
readCounter2 0
total readCounter 360687000
addCounter 360687000
addCounter2 0
```

You see over 360 Million increments!

Next the dual thread test shows 100% busy on both cores for the whole 5 seconds duration of the test.  However it's output shows only:

```
readCounter 88687000
readCounter2 134606500
totoal readCounter 223293500
addCounter 88687000
addCounter2 67303250
addFailure0
```

That's only 223 Million read increments. What is god's creation are those 2 CPU's doing for those 5 seconds to get less work done?

Any possible clue? And can you run the tests on your machine to see if you get different results?  One idea is that perhaps the VMWare dual core performance isn't what you would hope.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TickZoom.Utilities.TickZoom.Utilities
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ActiveMultiQueueTest
    {
        private volatile bool stopThread = false;
        private Exception threadException;
        private long addCounter;
        private long readCounter;
        private long addCounter2;
        private long readCounter2;
        private long addFailureCounter;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            stopThread = false;
            addCounter = 0;
            readCounter = 0;
            addCounter2 = 0;
            readCounter2 = 0;
        }


        [Test]
        public void TestSingleCoreSpeed()
        {
            var speedThread = new Thread(SpeedTestLoop);
            speedThread.Name = "1st Core Speed Test";
            speedThread.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            stopThread = true;
            speedThread.Join();
            if (threadException != null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Thread failed: ", threadException);
            }
            Console.Out.WriteLine("readCounter " + readCounter);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("readCounter2 " + readCounter2);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("total readCounter " + (readCounter + readCounter2));
            Console.Out.WriteLine("addCounter " + addCounter);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("addCounter2 " + addCounter2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestDualCoreSpeed()
        {
            var speedThread1 = new Thread(SpeedTestLoop);
            speedThread1.Name = "Speed Test 1";
            var speedThread2 = new Thread(SpeedTestLoop2);
            speedThread2.Name = "Speed Test 2";
            speedThread1.Start();
            speedThread2.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            stopThread = true;
            speedThread1.Join();
            speedThread2.Join();
            if (threadException != null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Thread failed: ", threadException);
            }
            Console.Out.WriteLine("readCounter " + readCounter);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("readCounter2 " + readCounter2);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("totoal readCounter " + (readCounter + readCounter2));
            Console.Out.WriteLine("addCounter " + addCounter);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("addCounter2 " + addCounter2);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("addFailure" + addFailureCounter);
        }

        private void SpeedTestLoop()
        {
            try
            {
                while (!stopThread)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                    {
                        ++addCounter;
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                    {
                        readCounter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                threadException = ex;
            }
        }

        private void SpeedTestLoop2()
        {
            try
            {
                while (!stopThread)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                    {
                        ++addCounter2;
                        i++;
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                    {
                        readCounter2++;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                threadException = ex;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Edit:  I tested the above on a quad core laptop w/o vmware and got similar degraded performance. So I wrote another test similar to the above but which has each thread method in a separate class.  My purpose in doing that was to test 4 cores.

Well that test showed excelled results which improved almost linearly with 1, 2, 3, or 4 cores.

With some experimentation now on both machines it appears that the proper performance only happens if main thread methods are on different instances instead of the same instance.

In other words, if multiple threads main entry method on on the same instance of a particular class, then the performance on a multi-core will be worse for each thread you add, instead of better as you might assume.

It almost appears that the CLR is "synchronizing" so only one thread at a time can run on that method. However, my testing says that isn't the case. So it's still unclear what's happening.

But my own problem seems to be solved simply by making separate instances of methods to run threads as their starting point.

Sincerely,
Wayne

EDIT:

Here's an updated unit test that tests 1, 2, 3, & 4 threads with them all on the same instance of a class. Using arrays with variables uses in the thread loop at least 10 elements apart.  And performance still degrades significantly for each thread added.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TickZoom.Utilities.TickZoom.Utilities
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MultiCoreSameClassTest
    {
        private ThreadTester threadTester;
        public class ThreadTester
        {
            private Thread[] speedThread = new Thread[400];
            private long[] addCounter = new long[400];
            private long[] readCounter = new long[400];
            private bool[] stopThread = new bool[400];
            internal Exception threadException;
            private int count;

            public ThreadTester(int count)
            {
                for( var i=0; i<speedThread.Length; i+=10)
                {
                    speedThread[i] = new Thread(SpeedTestLoop);
                }
                this.count = count;
            }

            public void Run()
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < count*10; i+=10)
                {
                    speedThread[i].Start(i);
                }
            }

            public void Stop()
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < stopThread.Length; i+=10 )
                {
                    stopThread[i] = true;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < count * 10; i += 10)
                {
                    speedThread[i].Join();
                }
                if (threadException != null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Thread failed: ", threadException);
                }
            }

            public void Output()
            {
                var readSum = 0L;
                var addSum = 0L;
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    readSum += readCounter[i];
                    addSum += addCounter[i];
                }
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Thread readCounter " + readSum + ", addCounter " + addSum);
            }

            private void SpeedTestLoop(object indexarg)
            {
                var index = (int) indexarg;
                try
                {
                    while (!stopThread[index*10])
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                        {
                            ++addCounter[index*10];
                        }
                        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                        {
                            ++readCounter[index*10];
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    threadException = ex;
                }
            }
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }


        [Test]
        public void SingleCoreTest()
        {
            TestCores(1);
        }

        [Test]
        public void DualCoreTest()
        {
            TestCores(2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TriCoreTest()
        {
            TestCores(3);
        }

        [Test]
        public void QuadCoreTest()
        {
            TestCores(4);
        }

        public void TestCores(int numCores)
        {
            threadTester = new ThreadTester(numCores);
            threadTester.Run();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            threadTester.Stop();
            threadTester.Output();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this in release mode without the debugger attached?

Comment: Note: your code does not have any thread synchronysation operations (locks or interlocked or something else). If you keep it likle this you may as well to use Random for all values as there is no way to have correctly running multithread code without synchronysation.

Comment: Jim, I'm tried it both ways. But the numbers discussed are during Debug mode.  Alexel..I'm aware of the need for locks and interleaved. Of course. But this is just experimental code. The experiment started with locks but performance was horrible--worse with more threads/cores. So I removed the locks to see if it's any faster.  Nope...still bad.  So I'm trying to isolate why are 4 cores running the same code w/o any locks so dog slow??? Do you know why?

Comment: The actual answer is L1 cache contention. With arrays watch out because every access to an array in C# reads the length of the array under the covers to do bounds checking. So any writes near the beginning of the array by any other thread will cause cache miss and great performance slowdowns.

Comment: SpeedTestLoop2 double increments `i` counter aka does i++ twice is this intentional. could we keep the `++` in a constant way, ++counter vs counter++, make code easier to read if a pattern is followed.

Comment: would be interesting what the result would  be if you removed `private volatile bool stopThread = false;`  two thread are looking over this vs 1 which as 0 contention. but still interesting... as you wouldn't think it would be so great of a diffidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> That's only 223 Million read increments. What is god's creation are those 2 CPU's doing for those 5 seconds to get less work done?

You're probably running into cache contention -- when a single CPU is incrementing your integer, it can do so in its own L1 cache, but as soon as two CPUs start "fighting" over the same value, the cache line it's on has to be copied back and forth between their caches each time each one accesses it. The extra time spent copying data between caches adds up *fast*, especially when the operation you're doing (incrementing an integer) is so trivial.

Comment: Interesting angle. Please see my edits from results of more experiments. Do you think L1 cache contention happens in the CLR when a thread's entry point is on the same instances of the class versus separate instances? If so, you might have it on the explanation.

Comment: For reference, this "memory swapping" problem is called "thrashing" -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)

Comment: Some more testing shows that with addition of using Interlocked for incrementing, then performance consistently: Decreases from only 1 to using 2 threads on a quad core, then it goes way UP on the 3rd thread and again decreases with adding a 4th thread.  It's clear there is something to do with "multi-CPUs" that I'm missing. There's some kind of "interaction" going on whether it be L1 caches r something else.

Comment: @Wayne - It's less to do with the threads running on the same instance and more to do with the memory locality of your member variables. Moving the counters to method locals would likely show much improved performance.

Comment: Okay. That's logical but this is simply a micro-benchmark test. In the real world these threads need to share data in some fashion. But so far, most techniques that I experiment with to share data result in seriously degraded performance.  In this case, they don't appear to even be sharing data. But when I do have the Interlocked.Increment() on the same counter--the performance goes bad also. Is there no way to share counters and get parallel performance? Maybe not.  Do you know any books that teach this stuff about data locality more in depth?

Comment: My testing shows that it's thread contention. If I use an array of counters, then performance decreases with the number of threads. If I allocate a counter class for each thread, performance increases linearly with the number of threads (i.e. 4 threads gives me 4x performance of 1 thread).

Comment: Thanks for trying this Jim. So anyone, why is there thread contention when the code doesn't have any locking specified? Does the CLR automatically do some locking under the covers? Or is it some kind of competition between cores for the memory cache? I'm very confused.

Comment: This PDF explains the L1 cache problem and testing proves that duskwuff gave the correct "hit the nail on the head" answer. http://www.multicoreinfo.com/research/intel/mem-issues.pdf  It turns out that performance can be SEVERELY impacted by 2 threads both writing to memory if that memory is "near" to each other--in the same cache line.  As long as they are far enough away from each other then you can get true parallel performance. So it's necessary to design in such a way that as shared writing to memory occurs as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You should probably test each setup at least 10 times and take the average
2. As far as I know, Thread.sleep is not exact - it depends on how the OS switches your threads
3. Thread.join is not immediate. Again, it depends on how the OS switches your threads

A better way to test would be to run a computationally intensive operation (say, sum from one to a million) on two configurations and time them. For example:

1. Time how long it takes to sum from one to a million
2. Time how long it takes to sum one to 500000 on one thread and one 500001 to 1000000 on another

You were right when you thought that two threads would work faster than one thread. But yours are not the only threads running - the OS has threads, your browser has threads, and so on. Keep in mind that your timings will not be exact and may even fluctuate.

Lastly, there are [other reasons](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~213/lectures/26-parallelism.pdf)(see slide 24) why threads work slower.

Comment: All the factors you mentioned were verified. That is nothing else was running on the machine, browser, etc. Only this process was taking CPU excpet a smidget of Task Manager to watch it. And also, I have run this test repeatedly and find that (as edited) if the threads start on the same instance of a class then they performance consistently degrades per thread added. But on separate instances, they performance significantly and almost linearly improves per thread added. Any explanation?

Comment: In that case, I agree with duskwuff. It's more likely that thrashing occurs when threads are on the same instance. Try this: instead of adding into readCounter and readCounter2, add into an array e.g. arr[0] and arr[5]. See what happens when you change the spacing between the two.

Comment: So using an array to force them into separate cache lines? Interesting. I'll use the same test code above and try exactly that. Give me a few minutes, please. Can't wait to try it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's quite a common technique to space them out, but the width of the space is system dependent...

Comment: Well for good measure, I put them 10 elements apart in a array of longs. I edited with the new unit test which is an little more elegant.  Well the performance still degrades pitifully for each additional thread on a quad core.  So far, the only common element is that they're on the same thread instance. Now I do have another test where each thread is on a separate instance. It works great until they share access to common "queue" which is what was the original purpose of the test. So perhaps "spacing" items inside that queue will do the trick. Let me know if you get other ideas.

Comment: Actually, larger spacing != better performance. It depends on how the cache organizes the cache lines. Are you locking the queue in any way?

Comment: The Queue's goal was to never allow any thread (core) to wait on another.  So the "queue" actually contains an array of queues equal to the number of processors. On Enqueue a thread will loop through using Interlocked.CompareExchange() to "lock" one and write to that queue.  Each queue is designed to allow reading/writing simultaneously so there are separate variables per queue to CompareExchange for threads that need to Dequeue.

Comment: Hey, I found the problem with arrays. It's L1 cache contention on the bounds checking fo the array.  That is, every access to an array compares the length of the array. If one thread is writing at index 0 of the array--then that is in the same cache line as the length which the other threads must read so it creates contention. In contrast if none of the threads write anywhere in the beginning of the array, then you get very fast performance with the threads writing separately in other pars of the array.

Comment: I started with your program and added multiple fields of type long between readcounter and readcounter2.  This showed improved performance as follows: with 0 to 5 longs field between readcounter readcounter2, no change.  With 6, multi-thread performance dropped even further.  But with 7 or more, multi-thread performance increased to 170% of single-thread performance.  So, more than 48 bytes between the fields provided the magic.